# CSS: How to fill a dynamic container that contains fixed sized elements?

Tags: html, css, height

Using **CSS** I am trying to get a div to fill a dynamicly sized container that also contains a fixed height div.

How can the `grey` div *(See snippet)* be made to fill the remaining available space only without overflowing?

- The  `grey` div `.Fill` cannot have anything inside it.
- I would prefer to use CSS `Flex` only as a **last resort**.

---

## FIDDLE

```css
html,body{height:100%;}
.Wrap{
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
}
.H40,.H60{
    display:block;
    padding:15px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.H40{        
    height:40%;
    background:#b00;
}
.H60{
    height:60%;
    background:#58c;
}
.Top{
    background:#8d5;
    height:40px;
}
.Fill{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrap">
    <div class="H40">
        <div class="Top">TOP</div>
        <div class="Fill">Fill this space</div>
    </div>
    <div class="H60">
        <div class="Top">TOP</div>
        <div class="Fill">Fill this space</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the `fill` divs won't contain anything...what is their purpose?

Comment: The fill divs contain javascript generated content that will overwrite anything already in the innerhtml.

Comment: incorrect but why ? :S

Comment: `calc` is definitely an option and is worthy of being an answer and a +1.

Comment: @akz because I don't want something like that, I want exactly that.

Comment: sorry i thought i was wrong that's why i deleted my comment @Paulie_D thanks :)

Comment: It should be pointed out that calc requires a set value (40px or whatever) to work...my solution does not. Just saying :)

Comment: @Paulie_D yup that's y i liked your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

use calc for that

```
.Fill{
    height:calc(100% - 40px);
    width:100%;
    background:#DDD;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pgys24ct/3/

Answer (score 2):

I think `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` will solve this.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L0tb8ouk/3/)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,body{height:100%;}
.Wrap{
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
}
.H40,.H60{
    display: table;
    padding:15px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

}
.H40{ 
    height:40%;
    background:#b00;
}
.H60{
    height:60%;
    background:#58c;
}
.Top{
    display: table-row;
    background:#8d5;
    height:40px;
}

.fill {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #ccc;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrap">
    <div class="H40">
        <div class="Top">TOP</div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="H60">
        <div class="Top">TOP</div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I already tried this method but had some issues with the ratios of the boxes contents. I will try again to make sure it wasn't my mistake before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add  `height:calc(100% - 20px);` in .Fill in your CSS.